# javascript login using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, authentication

I made a (really insecure) login system, I wanted to skip the login window in you already logged in, however it doesn't ask for the password anymore...

script:

```
var pass = "mypassword";
console.log( "pass = " + pass );

while (true) {

  if ( loginCookie != "" ) {
    console.log("already logged in");
    break;
  }

  var input = prompt( "Enter password:" );

  if ( input == pass ) {
    console.log( "right password!" );
    var loginCookie = document.cookie = "login=true" ;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not loading the cookie at the beginning.  Try something like:

```
var pass = "mypassword";
console.log( "pass = " + pass );

var loginCookie = document.cookie; // this
console.log("login cookie = " + loginCookie);

while (true) {

  if ( loginCookie != "" ) {
    console.log("already logged in");
    break;
  }

  var input = prompt( "Enter password:" );

  if ( input == pass ) {
    console.log( "right password!" );
    loginCookie = document.cookie = "login=true" ;
    break;
  }
}
```